# MPAndroidChart is not update after null value

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

I'm using the MPAndroidChart and am really enjoying it. But I have some problem with it

Here is my problem, My Barchart shows the value of October but if I change the parameter into January the barchart does not show because January has no value. And I change the parameter back to October, my barchart didn't show the chart

[image October with chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7CBq.png)

[image January without chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJPh7.png)

[image October without chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVUdk.png)

my code

```
        barDataSet1 = new BarDataSet(barEntries, "Suplier");
        barData1 = new BarData(barDataSet1);
        barChart1.setData(barData1);

        xAxis1 = barChart1.getXAxis();
        xAxis1.setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(supp));
        xAxis1.setCenterAxisLabels(false);
        xAxis1.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);

        xAxis1.setDrawAxisLine(false);
        xAxis1.setGranularity(1);
        xAxis1.setGranularityEnabled(true);
        xAxis1.setLabelRotationAngle(-60);

        barChart1.setDrawValueAboveBar(false);
        barChart1.getDescription().setText(" ");
        barChart1.animateY(1000);
        barChart1.setExtraOffsets(0, 0, 0, 30);

        barChart1.setDragEnabled(true);
        barChart1.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(6);
        barChart1.getAxisLeft().setAxisMinimum(0);
//        barChart1.getAxisLeft().setAxisMaximum(max + 2000);
        barChart1.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(false);
        barChart1.getAxisRight().setDrawAxisLine(false);
        barChart1.getAxisRight().setDrawGridLines(false);
        barChart1.getAxisRight().setDrawLabels(false);
        barChart1.getAxisLeft().setDrawGridLines(true);
        barChart1.setFitBars(true);
        barChart1.setTouchEnabled(true);
        barChart1.setPinchZoom(false);
        barChart1.setScaleEnabled(false);
        barChart1.notifyDataSetChanged();
        barChart1.invalidate();
        barChart1.refreshDrawableState();
```

I've been reading some solution with similar problem, they recommended to use `notifyDataSetChanged()` and `refreshDrawableState()` but I already write it in my code and my barchart didn't showing or refreshing

Please help me, what should I do?

Comment: Could you provide more code to be able to help you? Thanks

Comment: Thank u for your commend, I've added some code that I can share

Comment: Can't find a mistake in your code. Could you provide everything in one little project that I can import to make tests. Otherwise I can't find any error in your code. Just the Spinner with the whole chart. I am really trying to help. Thanks :)